# Multiple Properties on an Element/Object

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone explain how this works? =>   let li = event.target.parentNode ; So event.target is a reference to the dispatcher of the event and i know that .parentNode returns the parent of the specified node element etc. But how does the entire thing work together? do these things happen in sequential and the get added together or something?

```js
listDiv.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if(event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
  let li = event.target.parentNode ;
  let ul = li.parentNode ;
  ul.removeChild(li) ;
}
}) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tl;dr` `event.target` is the element that started the event, `parentNode` is that element's parent.

The entire thing works like this - `event` is an object containing all the relevant information about the event that was fired, including among other things `target` (the target of the event). This is the element that fired the element (e.g. the button that was clicked). This has all the properties of any other element you might select (with `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector`) - as such, it has a `parentNode` property which refers to the DOM node one level above it.

Comment: so basically this is getting the parent node of the element that started the event

Comment: Yep, pretty much @6Michael6Myers6.

Comment: so when youre working with a lot of properties connected to an element you just look at them like => event.target.parentNode  "ok let me flip over event.target and see what it returns ok i have blah.parentNode now"